# Show the inequality $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b^3 + (c+a)^3}} \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality

For all positive reals $a, b, c$, we wish to prove the inequality

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b^3 + (c+a)^3}} \ge 1$$

My approach was Hölder:

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b^3 + (c+a)^3}}\right)^2 \cdot \left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} b^3 + (c+a)^3 \right)^1 \ge (a+b+c)^3$$

So it would suffice to prove that $(a + b + c)^3 \ge a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + \sum_{\text{cyc}}(a+b)^3$. This is unfortunately *not* true. Another approach I came up with was by Titu's lemma:

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b^3 + (c+a)^3}} = \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a(b^3 + (c+a)^3)}} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{a(b^3 + (c+a)^3)}}$$

So it would suffice to prove $(a+b+c)^2 \ge \sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{a(b^3 + (c+a)^3)}$. This is, however not true. Take, for example, $a, b, c = 1, 2, 3$ to get $LHS = 36, RHS = 38.32$. The problem I find is that the inequality seems to be pretty sharp, since both my attempts with Hölder and C-S overshoot in the "first step". To counter this, I thought of using Jensen. Because of homogeneity, we may assume $a + b + c = 1$, and we have to prove $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b^3 + (1-b)^3}} \ge 1$. Although I was not able to make progress from here because I couldn't isolate each term to only one variable, as one often wishes to do in a Jensen approach.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h299899p1813496, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h273917_cyclic_inequality_with_sqrt

Comment: @MartinR that inequality is slightly different, nothing that can't be handled by rearrangement though.